# como puedo disparar la funcion mediante el boton?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Mi código consta de un select por provincias; cuando acciono la provincia para filtrar obtengo el resultado de clinics en esa provincia, lo que quiero es poder obtener ese resultado al accionar el botón, no mediante el propio select.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select, { SingleValue } from 'react-select'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import "./Modal.css";

interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean,
    closeModal: () => void
}


export const SearchFilterClinics : React.FC<Props> = ({ children, isOpen, closeModal,  }) => {

         ////filter

         type OptionType = {
            value: string;
            label: string;
          };
    
          
            const provincesList: OptionType[] = [
                { value: 'Todos', label: 'Todos' },
                { value: 'Valencia', label: 'Valencia' },
                { value: 'Alicante', label: 'Alicante' },
                { value: 'Castellón', label: 'Castellón' },
               
            ]

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFilteredSelect, setClinicListFilteredSelect] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [filterSelectClinic, setFilterSelectClinic] = useState<SingleValue<OptionType>>(provincesList[0]);

    const handleChangeSelect = async (provinceList:  SingleValue<OptionType>) => {
        getClinic().then((response) => {
            setClinicList(response);
            setClinicListFilteredSelect(response)
            setFilterSelectClinic(provinceList);
            filterSelect(provinceList );
          }).catch ((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });         
      }

       
      const filterSelect=(termSearch)=>{
        const resultFilterSelect = clinicList.filter((element) => {
          if(element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.value.toLowerCase() )
        
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFilteredSelect(resultFilterSelect);
      }

      const handleModalContainerClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation();

   

    return  (
                <>
                     <div className={`modal ${isOpen && "is-open"}`} onClick={closeModal}>
                         <div className="modal-container" onClick={handleModalContainerClick}>
                            <button className="modal-close" onClick={closeModal}>x</button>
                            {children}
                           
                            <div>
                                <h1>Encuentra tu clínica</h1>
                            </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <form>
                                        
                                        <label>Provincia</label>
                                            <Select 
                                                defaultValue={filterSelectClinic}
                                                options={provincesList}
                                                onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                                                />

                                                <button onClick={handleChangeSelect}>buscar</button> 
                                    </form>


                                { 
                                  
                                    clinicListFilteredSelect.map((clinicFilter) => (
                                        <div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.title}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.propsPhone}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.mobile}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.email}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.province} </div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.registry}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                          
                </>
            )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando tu function `handleChangeSelect` en tu botón y en select, para que la función solo se ejecute al hacer clic al botón remueve la función del atributo `onChange` en tu select, sino la función se ejecutará cuando el valor seleccionado cambie. De igual manera al poner una función dentro del atributo `onClick` de un botón como en tu ejemplo `<button onClick={handleChangeSelect}>buscar</button>` se ejecutará tan pronto como tu componente se monte. Si quieres que se ejecute cuando alguien de click, pon `handleChangeSelect` dentro de otra función así `<button onClick={() => handleChangeSelect}>buscar</button>`

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda.
E

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).